# How to detect current topic?

Tags: phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

Where would I store topic id?

As for socket, I can use:

```
def join("topic:" <> topic_id, _params, socket) do
    ...
    socket= assign(socket, :topic_id, topic_id)
    {:ok, socket}
end
```

That was at socket scope, but my users can join multiple topics at the same time, meaning that the above code will override the topic_id each time a new topic is joined, is that true?

What if I want to know which topic id is active in the `handle_in` ?

for example:

```
def handle_in("new_message", params, socket) do

    # what is the active topic id here?

end
```

I though of this:

```
def handle_in("new_message:" <> topic_id, params, socket) do

    # now, I know that topic_id is the active topic

end
```

Is there another way to do this? or this is how its done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `join` has a topic so that you can perform additional validation to check the user can subscribe to the topic (check their permissions, etc.)

You are correct, after there is a subscription to the topic, the channels are multiplexed over the socket.

If you wish to pass additional information for a particular message, the params is a common place to put them:

```
def handle_in("new_message", %{"topic_id" => topic_id}, socket) do
  ...
end
```

If you could explain why you need the topic_id then it could help answer your questy,

Comment: Thank you, I need the topic ID, as there might be topic related settings when messages are sent.. also, I thought that socket object is at channel scope, but then I found that its at user scope, so I wanted to make sure that I got it right, can the params inside socket object be encrypted?

Comment: Actually, users can join territories channels, territory ID will be used to read associated polygon, then I can check if sent lat, long message inside or outside the territory's polygon.. that's an example of why would I need topic ID..

Comment: Send territory_id in the params of you need it.

Answer (score 6):

Users can join multiple topics. You can access the current `topic` from the `socket` param in `handle_in`.

So assuming the room topic's base is `"topic"`, here's how you can get the topic id:

```
def handle_in("some_message", _params, socket) do
  "topic:" <> topic_id = socket.topic
  ...
end
```